# ActiveX freezes IE

Tags: activex

I created an activeX control to perform some actions, which take about 1 minute. During this action IE freezes completely. Is there a way to call the activeX control so that IE does not freeze?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a threading issue dealing with IE, so I don't think there is any way to do this.

Comment: Can I workaround it? If I were to add my activeX into an Iframe, it would cause the same issue, right?

Comment: Yeah, I think it would; I think the only way to really avoid this would be to spawn a new IE window, and invoke the control from within that one.  Or change the ActiveX control to spawn a worker thread, of course.

Answer (score 6):

You would have the same problem in any ActiveX host, not just IE. If you don't want to block the UI thread, then you need to change your ActiveX control to do its work on a secondary thread.

Comment: How would I do that? I created my control in C# and used Regasm to to register it.

Answer (score 4):

I had a simulair problem with my activeX that freezed IE. I managed to do a workaround, by letting my activeX control create new threads on client. Even tho the thread is doing its work, the activeX returns that its done and will unblock UI.

The tricky part is to know when the thread is done. You can find out by have a boolean property in your activeX, that you set to true when the thread is completed. From javascript you can keep invoke that property until its set to true.

Javascript:

```
var myActiveXObject = new ActiveXObject("myActiveX");

function startWork()
{
    myActiveXObject.startWork();

    setTimeout(checkIsDone(), 1000);
}

function checkIsDone()
{
    if(myActiveXObject.checkIsDone())
        workComplete();
    else
        setTimeout(checkIsDone(), 1000);
}
```

ActiveX:

```
private bool blnIsDone;

[ComVisible(true)]
public void startWork()
{
   blnIsDone = false;

   Thread myThread = new Thread(delegate()
   {
       ThreadedWork();
   });

   myThread.Start();
}

private ThreadedWork()
{
    //Do work

    blnIsDone = true;
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public bool checkIsDone()
{
   return blnIsDone;
}
```